# Intel UHD 630 Issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, intel-graphics

I've seen a number of reported questions surrounding Intel UHD 630 working with Ubuntu. In previous versions it seemed to be an outdated kernel but I'm having issues that makes it impossible to use Ubuntu 20.04.

Has anyone found any solid workarounds or have ideas on where to go from here? This is a new computer and looked to be fully supported by the Ubuntu OS.

Issues I've experienced:
Out of the box a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, 19.10, or 19.04 results in a frozen login screen. If I add "nomodeset" to Grub I can log in but the graphics card is not detected (shows as llvmpipe LLVM 9.0.1, 256 bits)and the performance is not practically usable.

Answer (score 0):

Intel UHD 630 is certified for Ubuntu 20.04, so there shouldn't be any issues:

https://ubuntu.com/certified/component/759

Have you tried with the latest version of 20.04 or even 22.04?

Login screen issues with 20.04 should be analysed to see what the root cause is.